# Polymer Paper-Radio-Group inside table

Tags: html-table, polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to add a paper-radio-group inside a table. When trying the wrap the paper-radio-group around the td-tags it stops working. The paper-radio-button  continue to work individually, but not as a group.

```
<tr>
 <td>
     <paper-radio-group selected="a">
     <paper-radio-button name="a"></paper-radio-button>
 </td>
 <td>
     <paper-radio-button name="b"></paper-radio-button>
     </paper-radio-group>
 </td>     
</tr>
```

Comment: maybe because it's not really valid markup? can you move the group outside of the table?

Comment: Unfortunately not. And since I'm going to have multiple groups inside the table, i'm not sure it would work to have it outside the table anyways

Comment: If you have more groups in the table you can't, that's just how elements wrap each other. Maybe you shouldn't use a table. But in this structure I guess you should just replicate the logic of groups with some JavaScript using tap event handlers to uncheck other elements when one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

`paper-radio-button` is a button that can be either checked or unchecked. User can tap the radio button to check or uncheck it.

Use a `<paper-radio-group>` to group a set of radio buttons. When radio buttons are inside a radio group, exactly one radio button in the group can be checked at any time.

Read the [Read me](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group) file of `paper-radio-button`. use [paper-radio-group](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group) to group a set of radio buttons.